# Equality for the Hill Estimator

Tags: probability-theory, substitution, parameter-estimation

Let us define the Hill estimator by

\begin{align}
\widehat{\gamma}_H:=\frac{\int_{X_{n-k,n}}^\infty \log u-\log X_{n-k,n} \: dF_n(u)}{1-F_n(X_{n-k,n})}=\frac n k \int_{X_{n-k,n}}^\infty \log u-\log X_{n-k,n} \: dF_n(u),
\end{align}
since we denote by $F_n$ the empirical distribution function. $X_{n-k,n}$ is the intermediate order statistic. 
We can also write:
\begin{align}
\widehat{\gamma}_H := \frac 1 k \sum_\limits{i=0}^{k-1} \log X_{n-i,n}-\log X_{n-k,n}.
\end{align}
How can we deduce now, that

$$
\widehat{\gamma}_H = \int_0^1 \log X_{n-\lfloor ks \rfloor, n} - \log X_{n-k,n} \: \mathrm{d}s
$$
with $\operatorname{floor}(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ holds?

I hope someone can give me a hint or explain it to me.

Source: [click here](https://books.google.de/books?id=catZCl17d7gC&lpg=PA76&hl=de&pg=PA76#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Are $\widehat\gamma_H$ and $\widehat\gamma_h$ the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the First and second statement are the definition of this Hill estimator. And the last statement seems to follow from this Definition, but I don't see it. I'm sorry it should have been a big H for all of them for the name Hill estimator.

Comment: "How can we deduce now, that" For each $i$, what is the length of the $s$-interval on which $X_{n-\lfloor ks \rfloor, n}=X_{n-i, n}$? QED.

Comment: Lowest value for s: $ks=i$, so $s=i/k$ Highest value for s: Let $\epsilon >0$ small. $ks=i+1-\epsilon$, so $s=(i+1-\epsilon)/k $. Length of the interval is $(1-\epsilon)/k $

Comment: So this is related to a Riemann sum, which gives us in the limit $1/k$ as a coefficient.

Comment: This is really just a matter of understanding what the last integral means... To do so, decompose the integral on $(0,1)$ into the sum of the integrals on the intervals $I_i=(i/n,(i+1)/n)$ for $0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$, and note that, for each such $i$ and every $s$ in $I_i$, $$\log X_{n-\lfloor ks \rfloor, n} - \log X_{n-k,n}=\log X_{n-i,n} - \log X_{n-k,n}$$